# get Comma separated string based on multiple bit value in sql select query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table in which I have multiple bit column like LH1,LH2,LH3,RH1,
RH2,RH3. 
(This is example only and in original database I have more then 20 bit column.LH means Left Hand and RH means Right Hand. Same way I have Right Eye,Left Eye,Right Foot,Left Foot etc)

Now based on those bit value I want to get a comma separated string.

For Exapmle `iF LH1,RH1,RH2 and LH3 are true then I want '1,3' as LH and '1,2' as RH.`

and `IF  LH3,RH1,RH2 and RH3 are true then I want '1' as LH and '1,2,3' as RH.`

I went through below link but it is not useful in my case

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/112408/join-with-comma-separated-values-in-sql-server

Thanks

Comment: Are you using both mysql and sql-server databases? If not kindly tag only respective DBMS

Comment: I am using Sql Server.

Comment: Are the column names always two characters and one number?

Comment: Unpivot the rows to normalize the data then it becomes much easier.

Comment: @Shnugo, Yes two characters and one numbe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You design is not Okay... Whenever you see the need to add **numbered columns** like `LH1, LH2,LH3` this cries for related child tables! But nevertheless you could create the appropriate statement dynamically:

This table *mocks-up* your table

```
CREATE TABLE Dummy(ID INT IDENTITY,ControlString VARCHAR(100),LH1 BIT,LH2 BIT,LH3 BIT,RH1 BIT,RH2 BIT);
INSERT INTO Dummy VALUES
 ('All True',1,1,1,1,1) 
,('All LH True',1,1,1,0,0) 
,('All RH True',0,0,0,1,1)
,('LH1 and RH1',1,0,0,1,0)
,('LH2,3 and RH1,2',0,1,1,1,1);
GO
```

The statement you'd need was this:

```
SELECT ID
      ,ControlString
      ,CASE WHEN LH1=1 THEN ',1' ELSE '' END+CASE WHEN LH2=1 THEN ',2' ELSE '' END+CASE WHEN LH3=1 THEN ',3' ELSE '' END AS [LH]
      ,CASE WHEN RH1=1 THEN ',1' ELSE '' END+CASE WHEN RH2=1 THEN ',2' ELSE '' END AS [RH] 
FROM Dummy
```

--I'll use *meta-data* to find all column's names and create the statement on string-base:

```
DECLARE @cmd AS VARCHAR(MAX);
WITH AllColumns AS
(
    SELECT LEFT(COLUMN_NAME,2) AS Location
          ,SUBSTRING(COLUMN_NAME,3,1000) AS Indx
          ,COLUMN_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='Dummy' AND LEN(COLUMN_NAME)=3
)
SELECT @cmd='SELECT ID,ControlString,' + STUFF(
(
     SELECT ',' + STUFF(
                        ((SELECT '+CASE WHEN ' + grp.COLUMN_NAME + '=1 THEN '',' + grp.Indx + ''' ELSE '''' END' 
                          FROM AllColumns AS grp 
                          WHERE grp.Location=AllColumns.Location 
                          FOR XML PATH('')) + ' AS ' + QUOTENAME(Location)
                        ),1,1,''
                       )
     FROM AllColumns
     GROUP BY Location
     FOR XML PATH('')
    ),1,1,''
) + ' FROM Dummy';

EXEC( @cmd);
GO
```

--Clean-up

```
DROP TABLE Dummy;
```

The result

```
ID  ControlString   LH      RH
1   All True        ,1,2,3  ,1,2
2   All LH True     ,1,2,3  
3   All RH True             ,1,2
4   LH1 and RH1     ,1      ,1
5   LH2,3 and RH1,2 ,2,3    ,1,2
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data structure id "de-normalized" (or "pivoted") which always makes subseqent processing harder. So the first step is to "normalize" (or "unpivot") that data which makes the next steps simpler.

It isn't necessary to use an "unpivot" command to do this: In SQL Server I prefer to use CROSS APPLY with VALUES to achieve the first part (in the CTE below). Then it is a matter of using "FOR XML PATH" and STUFF() to achieve the comma separated strings.

From the following sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([id] int, [lh1] bit, [lh2] bit, [lh3] bit, [lh4] bit, [rh1] bit, [rh2] bit, [rh3] bit, [rh4] bit)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([id], [lh1], [lh2], [lh3], [lh4], [rh1], [rh2], [rh3], [rh4])
VALUES
    (1001, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0),
    (1002, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0),
    (1003, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0),
    (1004, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0),
    (1005, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1),
    (1006, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0),
    (1007, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (1008, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1)
;
```

and then this query:

```
;with CTE as (
        select
                id, ca.colname, colvalue
        from table1
        cross apply (
              values
                    ('lh1',case when lh1 = 1 then 1 end)
                  , ('lh2',case when lh2 = 1 then 2 end)
                  , ('lh3',case when lh3 = 1 then 3 end)
                  , ('lh4',case when lh4 = 1 then 4 end)
                  , ('rh1',case when rh1 = 1 then 1 end)
                  , ('rh2',case when rh2 = 1 then 2 end)
                  , ('rh3',case when rh3 = 1 then 3 end)
                  , ('rh4',case when rh4 = 1 then 4 end)
             ) ca (colname, colvalue)
         where ca.colvalue IS NOT NULL
        ) 
SELECT
  t.id, l.h as lh, r.h as rh
FROM table1 t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT
      STUFF((SELECT
        ',' + CAST(cte.colvalue AS char(1))
      FROM cte
      WHERE t.id = cte.id
      AND cte.colname like 'lh%'
      ORDER BY cte.colname
      FOR xml PATH (''))
      , 1, 1, '')) AS l (h) 
CROSS APPLY (SELECT
      STUFF((SELECT
        ',' + CAST(cte.colvalue AS char(1))
      FROM cte
      WHERE t.id = cte.id
      AND cte.colname like 'rh%'
      ORDER BY cte.colname
      FOR xml PATH (''))
      , 1, 1, '')) AS r (h) 


         select
                id, ca.colname, colvalue
        from table1
        cross apply (
              values
                    ('lh1',case when lh1 = 1 then 1 end)
                  , ('lh2',case when lh2 = 1 then 2 end)
                  , ('lh3',case when lh3 = 1 then 3 end)
                  , ('lh4',case when lh4 = 1 then 4 end)
                  , ('rh1',case when rh1 = 1 then 1 end)
                  , ('rh2',case when rh2 = 1 then 2 end)
                  , ('rh3',case when rh3 = 1 then 3 end)
                  , ('rh4',case when rh4 = 1 then 4 end)
             ) ca (colname, colvalue)
         where ca.colvalue IS NOT NULL
         order by id, colname, colvalue
```

You get this result:

```
+----+------+------+------+
|    |  id  |  lh  |  rh  |
+----+------+------+------+
|  1 | 1001 | 1    | 3    |
|  2 | 1002 | 2    | 1    |
|  3 | 1003 | 3    | 2    |
|  4 | 1004 | 2,4  | 3    |
|  5 | 1005 | 1,3  | 2,4  |
|  6 | 1006 | NULL | 1,3  |
|  7 | 1007 | 1,4  | NULL |
|  8 | 1008 | 2,3  | 1,4  |
+----+------+------+------+
```

Comment: The OP needs to see which column was true. The result `1,1` does not reflect this...